# Send Slack Modal Data to Third Party

Tags: slack, slack-api

Is it possible to send data gathered from a Slack modal to an external site?

I’m using [Slack Bolt for JavaScript](https://slack.dev/bolt-js)

I’ve tried `receiver.router.post('siteToSendData', (req, res) => { // You're working with an express req and res now. console.log('post to slack') res.send(dataToSend); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot send the captured data directly to a third party site. 
What you can do instead, is process the submission event. 
https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#handling_submissions

**Slack Bolt Reference :** https://slack.dev/bolt-js/concepts#view_submissions

The captured data will be sent to your application first. You can then re-route it to the desired external website.

Here is example of payload that you can expect:
 https://api.slack.com/reference/interaction-payloads/views

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to re-route the data after processing the submission event? I don't see a way to send the data _out_ of Slack in any of the documentation.

Comment: In the link I've provided as 'Bolt' reference, it talks about listening to view_submission events, by using built-in view() method. To send the data to external site , you can use axios or fetch (depending on your implementation) within 'View()' to make a call to external site and send the data.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't realize I could use external modules with Slack Bolt. Should have realized it was just Node. Thank you!